# List all the indexes in a pirticular schema

Tags: unix, db2

How to List **all the Indexes** for a particular schema of a Database in DB2 using Unix Command line processor.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Even if the question is already answered, I prefer to put a complete question because this site is used by people with different technical knowledge.

From the DB2CLP you can execute:

```
db2 "select INDSCHEMA, INDNAME, TABSCHEMA, TABNAME, COLNAMES from syscat.indexes"
```

The result will include the indexes from the catalog. If you just want the user indexes:

```
db2 "select INDSCHEMA, INDNAME, TABSCHEMA, TABNAME, COLNAMES from syscat.indexes where tabschema not like 'SYS%'"
```